# Tengo 4 cards de producto y solo 1 reacciona al evento

Tags: javascript, html

`productos` es un array con 4 productos.

El problema es que cuando pongo añadir al carrito, únicamente la primer card es la que devuelve el alert, las demás no hacen nada. No sé qué problema puedo tener, o dónde me equivoqué.
Ya intenté pasar de `getElementById` A `ByClassName` y tampoco funciona.

```js
let listaProd = ''
productos.forEach(item=> {
    listaProd +=`
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <img src="${item.image}" class="card-img-top" alt="${item.title}">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">${item.title}</h5>
      <h5>$${item.price}</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Descripcion del producto</p>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" id="carrito" >añadir al carrito</button>
    </div>
  </div>`
})
document.getElementById("productos").innerHTML=listaProd

let carrito = document.getElementById("carrito");
carrito.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    alert("hiciste click")
})
```

Comment: Los identificadores [deben ser únicos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)...

Comment: En lugar de id que debe ser único, puedes hacer class="carrito" y capturar con document.getElementsByClassName('carrito')

Answer (score 0):

Par seleccionar un ítem de una lista array, éste ítem debe ser llamado por su `class`.
Si todos los ítem tienen el mismo ID, y si se les llama por este ID, no funcionará.
Entonces sería mejor usar una clase.

La clase del botón puede tener `carrito`:

```
<button class="carrito btn btn-primary">añadir al carrito</button>
```

Y un forma de llamarlo podría ser usando `forEach` y asignarle una función:

```
// Seleccionar todas las clases:
let carrito = document.querySelectorAll(".carrito");
// Recorrer todas
carrito.forEach( function(agregar) { 
 // Al hacer click:
 agregar.addEventListener("click", tocame);
 // Agrego una función
 function tocame() {
  alert("hiciste click")
 }
 
})
```

Comment: Gracias, pude solucionarlo. Saludos!